# Change date format as dd/mm/yyyy in php

Tags: date, formatting

Hi I want to echo date format in dd/mm/yyyy format, currently it is displaying as yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Any further info? Language, operating system? `echo` is used all over the place

Comment: Please make sure to provide *all* details required for answering your question. Tag the question with the appropriate language, framework, OS, etc. Also, don't duplicate the entire question in the title.

Comment: In which language should we think?

Comment: Could you deliver more informations about your problem, like used language, current code?

Comment: I am using php to to echo date format from yyyy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will be helpful .... written in PHP

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 

$adm_date = date_create($row[0]); 

if(preg_match('@([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})@', $adm_date, $n)) {

$converted=$n[3]."/".$n[2]."/".$n[1];

echo $converted; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but it didn't work. There are many fields in the table date is one of them, by using above code it is giving error like Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in

Comment: @vinay kindly refer this link http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: this is the same you have given me..and not working.

Comment: @vinay i have updated the above code sure it will help

Comment: @vinay the above code will be helpful ..if you get the error again do let me know

Comment: still it is giving error Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home/aadlabs/public_html/MDCOL/studentregister.php on line 59

Comment: <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$adm_date = date_create($row[0]);
?><?php echo date_format($adm_date, 'd/m/y'); ?>

Comment: @vinay now i have updated the coded ..just have a look .. and let me know ..